# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on browser when opening dtale with Eclipse Pydev

Tags: python, pandas, flask, data-analysis, pydev

Opening a dtale sheet using Eclipse Pydev on Windows leads to ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on browser. The same code works on spyder and jupyter however. I know dtale uses a flask backend but I am inexperienced in flask. Any advice or workaround is welcome but I specifically want to use pydev because of familiarity. The code and output is attached below.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import dtale
import dtale.app as dtale_app

# Class=input("Enter Class: ").upper()
Class="A"
pathname="Data/"+Class+".xlsx"
df=pd.read_excel(pathname,header=None)
d=dtale.show(df)
print(d)
d.open_browser()
```

output:

```
2021-07-09 21:13:28,554 - INFO     - NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6  ...  4089  4090  4091  4092  4093  4094  4095
0    12   22   35   45   69   74   79  ...   -21   -14   -14   -25   -28   -11     8
1   -56  -50  -64  -91 -135 -140 -134  ...  -114  -138  -159  -172  -180  -173  -162
2   -37  -22  -17  -24  -31  -20   -5  ...   -23   -14    -5    -3     7     3     4
3   -31  -43  -39  -39   -9   -5   18  ...   -40   -23    -1    11    12    -6    10
4    14   26   32   25   16    8    8  ...   -29   -35   -51   -55   -58   -32    -6
..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
95 -133 -144 -113  -74  -41  -41  -61  ...   -70   -58   -62   -71   -79   -83   -87
96   -3   -3  -12  -24  -34  -42  -41  ...    31    54    61    55    42    30    19
97  -51  -42  -39  -47  -51  -46  -29  ...    -7   -16   -18    -9     2    -2     0
98   56   55   38   -5  -47  -72  -79  ...    36    41    14   -27   -45   -32    -4
99  -36  -71 -120 -150 -160 -133  -96  ...    39    57    44    41    14     3   -13

[100 rows x 4096 columns]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try hitting http://localhost:40000/dtale/main/1 in the browser. If that works then you can update your code to use

d = dtale.show(df, host=‘localhost’)

sometimes the computer name is accessible from the browser. You can also try ‘0.0.0.0’ as the host.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add localhost and use subprocess:

```
d = dtale.show(df, host='localhost', subprocess=False)
```

Also, check your windows firewall settings: https://github.com/man-group/dtale#issues-with-windows-firewall

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that your IDE must also be enabled in the windows firewall for it to work.